# Is my sql query correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using table below 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmg2C.png

Retrieve the names of Employees who have the same E_level values as Mat David and also are working at the same store as Mat David.

```
SELECT E_fname,E_lname
FROM Employee E,
(SELECT E_Level
FROM Employee E
WHERE UPPER(E.E_lname) = ‘DAVID’
AND UPPER(E.Efname) = ‘MAT’) elevel,
(SELECT E_Store_ID
FROM Employee E
WHERE UPPER(E.E_lname) = ‘DAVID’
AND UPPER(E.Efname) = ‘MAT’
) estoreid
WHERE E.E_level = elevel.E_level
AND E.Store_ID = estoreid.Store_ID
AND UPPER(E.E_lname) != ‘DAVID’
AND UPPER(E.Efname) != ‘MAT’;



SELECT E_fname,E_lname
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.E_level = 
(SELECT E_level
FROM Employee E
WHERE UPPER(E.E_lname) = ‘DAVID’
AND UPPER(E.Efname) = ‘MAT’)
AND E.E_Store_ID = 
(SELECT E_Store_ID
FROM Employee E
WHERE UPPER(E.E_lname) = ‘DAVID’
AND UPPER(E.Efname) = ‘MAT’)
AND UPPER(E.E_lname) != ‘DAVID’
AND UPPER(E.Efname) != ‘MAT’;
```

these are my attempts. am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E_fname,E_lname
  FROM Employee E
    WHERE E_level = (SELECT E_Level
                      FROM Employee E
                        WHERE UPPER(E.E_lname) = 'DAVID'
                          AND UPPER(E.E_fname) = 'MAT')
      AND E_store_ID = (SELECT E_Store_ID
                        FROM Employee E
                          WHERE UPPER(E.E_lname) = 'DAVID'
                            AND UPPER(E.E_fname) = 'MAT'
                        )
      AND UPPER(E.E_lname) != 'DAVID'
      AND UPPER(E.E_fname) != 'MAT';
```